# Evaluation contexts: outside-in vs inside-out

Tags: pl.programming-languages, lambda-calculus, functional-programming, operational-semantics

I heard that there exist two styles to define an evaluation context: outside-in and inside-out.  Can someone give the definitions?  Why are they so named (inside-out and outside-in)?  What is the difference?  Some examples would be appreciated.

Comment: See 4.3 of Danvy et al, _Defunctionalized Interpreters for Call-by-Need Evaluation_, 2010.